# Print LaTeX in 8.5x11 inch format

Tags: pdftex, paper-size

Linux defaults to A4 paper size rather than letter. The only answer I found online was to run `pdflatex` with the `-t` flag.

```
$ pdflatex -t letter myfile.tex
```

but I get the error:

```
warning: Could not open char translation file `letter.tcx'.
```

The first line of my file is

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
```

because I'm using someone else's template, found here: http://www.terpconnect.umd.edu/~briankw/resources/resume.cls.

How can I make 8.5x11 inch pdf's with latex, and still use this template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no `-t` option for selecting the paper format as is the case for `dvips`; but `pdflatex` knows the option `-translate-file` and accepts abbreviations for options, as long as they are unambiguous: thus that cryptic warning.

All TeX distributions I know of, set A4 as the default page size for PDF files generated by `pdftex` or `pdflatex`. This can be modified at installation time.

A good solution is to say

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

that exploits **geometry**'s features to pass the paper size to `pdflatex` without modifying the standard page make up parameters. It's not necessary to say

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

because `letterpaper` is a default option; but it doesn't hurt, either.

Of course, any class can be used in place of **article**:

```
\documentclass[optionone,optiontwo]{myclass}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
```

Just add the `geometry` line after the class declaration.

Comment: I'm using someone else's template, so changing the \documentclass creates errors. I posted a link to the template I'm using. Maybe there's a way that I could pass "letterpaper" in. But I don't know how.

Comment: Just add `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` after the `\documentclass{resume}` line.

Comment: I usually use `\usepackage{hyperref}` instead of `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`, for the same effect.

Comment: @Jukka: **hyperref** has many other effects, though. Let's say that using it dispenses from loading **geometry** or setting the parameters shown in Count Zero's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Most document classes accept options to modify the page size to fit any standard paper size, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{report}
```

If you convert then to PDF, it might happen that the page is typeset correctly, but the paper size is different. To avoid this, you can insert into your preamble:

```
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
```

This tells pdfLaTeX to match the paper and the page size.